# Calculate monthly/quarterly/year delta in R

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series

Below is what the data frame looks like, how could I create columns to the right that summarize the month over month difference, quarter over quarter difference and year over year difference in R? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Convert to `ts` object first. See: http://faculty.washington.edu/ezivot/econ424/Working%20with%20Time%20Series%20Data%20in%20R.pdf

Comment: thanks. are there any other ways w/o having to convert them into a time series?

Comment: To my knowledge, no.  Check `lubridate` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
# test data
DF <- data.frame(Date = c(paste0(month.abb, 2015), paste0(month.abb, 2016)), 
                 Aggressive = seq(24)^2, Moderate = seq(24)^2)

Diff <- function(x, k) x - c(rep(NA, k), head(x, -k))
transform(DF, Aggressive_Mon = Diff(Aggressive, 1),
                Moderate_Mon = Diff(Moderate, 1),
                Aggressive_Qtr = Diff(Aggressive, 3),
                Moderate_Qtr = Diff(Moderate, 3),
                Aggressive_Yr = Diff(Aggressive, 12),
                Moderate_Yr = Diff(Moderate, 12))
```

Next time please do not use images to show the data but instead show the output from `dput(DF)`.